# $_SESSION not working with localhost or a webdomine

Tags: php, session

i'm using raw php and using $_SESSION but in every request the $_SESSION is reinstating and all the  $_SESSION variables are emptied i used `http://127.0.0.1/` insted of `http://localhost/` and the $_SESSION work fine but now i update my code to server and the $_SESSION is break again so please any help on and many thnks in advance.

my code

functions.php

```
function login_user($UserName, $user_role)
{
    $_SESSION["UserID"] = get_user_id($UserName, $user_role);
    $_SESSION["UserName"] = $UserName;
    $_SESSION["UserRole"] = $user_role;
    $_SESSION["UserLogged"] = 1;

    if($user_role == "s") {
        $url = get_home_url() . '/student/student-profile.php';
        header("Location: $url");
    } else if ($user_role == "i") {
        $url = get_home_url() . '/instructor/instructor-profile.php';
        header("Location: $url");
    } else if ($user_role == "a") {
        $url = get_home_url() . '/admin/admin-profile.php';
        header("Location: $url");
    }
}
```

login.php

```
<?php

include ('../autoload.php');

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) &&
        !empty($_POST['login_password']) &&
        !empty($_POST['user_type']))
    {
        if(get_user_password($_POST['username'], $_POST['user_type']) == $_POST['login_password'])
        {
            login_user($_POST['username'], $_POST['user_type']);
        } else {
            echo 'Password incorrect please try again...';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Please fill all fields and try again...';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Some thing went wrong please try again...';
}
```

student.php

```
<?php

include ('../autoload.php');

//check if user logged in or not redirect to home page
if(!array_key_exists('UserLogged', $_SESSION)){
    $url = get_home_url() . '/home.php';
    header("Location: $url");
}

get_header();

echo '<wml>';

echo '<card id="student-profile" title="Student Profile">';
echo '<br/>';
echo '<h2 align="center">Welcome:</h2>';
echo '<h4 align="center">'.$_SESSION['UserName'].'</h4>';
echo '<br/>';
echo '<p align="center">';
echo '<a href="allsongs.php">INFO</a><br/><br/>';
echo '</p>';
echo '</card>';
echo '</wml>';
```

autoload.php

```
<?php

include 'helpers/session.php';
include 'helpers/db_functions.php';
include 'helpers/functions.php';
```

session.php

```
<?php
SESSION_START();
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and we don't know what your code looks like and if any (big) differences in PHP versions, if one is really old..? Hard to say here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it return Undefined Index UserName that the  $_SESSION variable, and i'm using php 5.5.12

Comment: Show your code what you tried ??

Comment: @Fadi then that tells me that the session array hasn't been assigned. Showing your full code and for all pages will help us help you ;-)

Comment: @Fadi please show your code.

Comment: `$url = get_home_url() . '/student/student-profile.php;` if that's your real code, it's missing a quote for it. `$url = get_home_url() . '/student/student-profile.php';`

Comment: @ Fred -ii- , @Anant  , this my code

Comment: did you not include `session_start();` everywhere where sessions are used?

Comment: you forgot to start session. `session_start();`. Write it on top of each page just after `<?php`

Comment: @Fred -ii- ,@Anant , yes i'm session_start(); in every page but why is it work only with  http://127.0.0.1/

Comment: seeing you did start the session, is the html form correct, using POST method and the inputs all bear their matching name attributes? You also may be trying to do some cross-domain differences with 127... and localhost.

Comment: @Fadi  either include `session.php` to all your other pages or write the code what i have given to you. also `SESSION_START();` needs to be `session_start();`

Comment: another problem could be a variable scope issue with the `login_user()` function. Try adding `global`s for the variables etc. that's about all I can think of at this point.

Comment: Make sure you are not using `www.domain` vs just `domain`